# Copy String byte Array contents to another array and Prefix 0 to single digits in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have String array named "string_array_packet" which contains

FA,11,1,4,90,6C,E7,72,0,0,0,8,80,0,8,80,7B,

Now i need to copy the contents between first and last index of array and store it in another array and then need to prefix 0 to single digits

11,1,4,90,6C,E7,72,0,0,0,8,80,0,8,80,

What I have done so far is

```
var sourceStartIndex = 1;
var destinationLength = string_array_packet.Length - 2;
Console.WriteLine(string_array_packet.Length);
Console.WriteLine(destinationLength);
var destinationStartIndex = 0;
var destination = new string[destinationLength];
Array.Copy(string_array_packet, sourceStartIndex, 
    destination, destinationStartIndex, destinationLength);
```

Not sure how to proceed after this.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to prefix 0 to single digits"?

Comment: Need to replace 1 by 01

Comment: Is the initial packet a string "FA,11,1,4,90,6C,E7,72,0,0,0,8,80,0,8,80,7B," or a byte array?

Comment: @ThymiosK I'd say it's a `string[]` given the OP said "I have String array named "string_array_packet""

Comment: public static string[] string_array_packet;

Comment: @Aomine Then I guess your answer is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done much easier with Linq (`using System.Linq` required):

```
var sourceStartIndex = 1;
var destinationLength = string_array_packet.Length - 2;

var strings = string_array_packet.Skip(sourceStartIndex)
                                 .Select(x => x.Length == 1 ? "0" + x :x)
                                 .Take(destinationLength)
                                 .ToArray();
```

Alternatively, if you're not familiar with the Enumerable methods then add the following imperative approach to complete your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < destination.Length; i++)
    if (destination[i].Length == 1)
        destination[i] = "0" + destination[i];
```

Comment: Above solution works but it adds last element . I don't need last element

Comment: @Mishty then change the destination length from `string_array_packet.Length - 2` to `string_array_packet.Length - 3`